# Should I use symbolic links or hard links (and junctions) for web server?

Tags: linux, apache2, symbolic-link, hardlink, junction-points

I understand the differences between hard links (or junctions/soft links for directories) and symbolic links.

Are there performance/security benefits for one or the other for web server usage?

Comment: Hard links will perform slightly better than symbolic links, but with Linux caching the convenience and greater familiarity should win for symbolic links.  The performance hit will be hard to detect.

Comment: @chicks that makes sense, I guess I also just didn't know which one was more common, reading about both of them just now made them seem like they were (mostly) ways of doing the same thing

Comment: Hard links don't work across file systems and fewer folks are familiar with them so I try to avoid them to avoid confusion.  They're similar for sure.